# How to find matches in source order

Tags: c#, regex, sorting

Service rows are extracted from invoice text using templates:

```
    string text = @"Invoice 1234
Contract 45/5:
Room Cleaning    100,00
Some other row
Rental      200,00 
Before VAT  300,00
VAT          30,00
Total       330,00
";

    List<string> templates = new List<string>() { "Rental.*", ".*Cleaning.*$" };
    List<string> results = new List<string>();  
    foreach (string template in templates)
    {
      var matches = Regex.Matches(text, template, RegexOptions.Multiline);
      for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count(); i++)
        results.Add(matches[i].Value);
    }
```

Result rows in results list are in template order:

> ```
> Rental      200,00 
> Room Cleaning    100,00
> ```

In invoice cleaning is before rentar. How to get result list in same order as in source:

> ```
> Room Cleaning    100,00
> Rental      200,00
> ```

.NET 7 RegExp GroupCollection does not contain source text position or order. So it is not possible to sort results according to same order as in source:

```
namespace System.Text.RegularExpressions
{
  public class GroupCollection : ICollection<Group>, IEnumerable<Group>, IEnumerable, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Group>>, IList<Group>, IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<string, Group>>, IReadOnlyCollection<Group>, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, Group>, IReadOnlyList<Group>, ICollection, IList
  {
    public Group this[int groupnum] { get; }
    public Group this[string groupname] { get; }
    public int Count { get; }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get; }
    public bool IsSynchronized { get; }
    public object SyncRoot { get; }
    public IEnumerable<Group> Values { get; }
    public bool ContainsKey(string key);
    public void CopyTo(Array array, int arrayIndex);
    public void CopyTo(Group[] array, int arrayIndex);
    public bool TryGetValue(string key, [NotNullWhen(true)] out Group? value);
  }
}
```

Code is runnign in ASP.NET MVC controller in .NET 7

Comment: "GroupCollection does not contain source text position" - true, but the individual `Group`s do have an `Index` property

Comment: Shoud Index added to result list and result list should sorted by this property after all matches are found? Or is it possible to get results in Index order?

Comment: The first option is possible. For the second option, you would need a single Regex instead of two, e.g. `"(Rental|Cleaning).*"`

Comment: Some templates have containing condition instead of start of. I modified question and changed cleaning template to this. Will __Rental.*|.*Cleaning.*$__ also work? In this case all templates can merged into single template. This prevents also duplicate matches which may occur is multiple templates are used.

Comment: Perhaps you can make use of a single regex with capture groups and a backreference. The values of interest are in group 1 and group 3. See https://regex101.com/r/Y5p40Q/1 and https://regex101.com/r/EoKtfF/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest first match *all* `(name, value)` pairs with a help of regex:

```
var records = Regex
  .Matches(text,
    @"^\s*(?<name>[\p{L} \t]+?)[^\S\r\n]+(?<value>[0-9]+,[0-9]{2})\s*$",
     RegexOptions.Multiline)
  .Select(match => (name: match.Groups["name"].Value, 
                    value: match.Groups["value"].Value));
```

this will provide an enumeration of tuples (note, that the order is kept)

```
(Room Cleaning, 100,00)
(Rental, 200,00)
(Before VAT, 300,00)
(VAT, 30,00)
(Total, 330,00)
```

And then, having the enumeration you can filter out the required records with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

List<string> templates = new List<string> { "Rental", "Cleaning" };

List<string> results = Regex
  .Matches(text,
    @"^\s*(?<name>[\p{L} \t]+?)[^\S\r\n]+(?<value>[0-9]+,[0-9]{2})\s*$",
     RegexOptions.Multiline)
  .Select(match => (name: match.Groups["name"].Value, 
                    value: match.Groups["value"].Value))
  .Where(pair => templates.Any(template => pair.name.Contains(template)))
  .Select(pair => $"{pair.name} {pair.value}")
  .ToList();
```